# Laravel Forge Deployment for multi server instances

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

[image]

It seems that Laravel forge has the following deploy process

```
(1) Git push from my PC to Bitbucket
(2) Webhook from Bitbucket to Forge server
(3) Copy deploy-script file and execute it on my own server via SSH from Forge server
```

Sample deploy-script file

```
cd /path/to/dir
git pull origin sample-repo
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-scripts
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
php artisan migrate
```

It's no problem if the target server is only one. But I have some instances for load balancing. In this case, I think Laravel forge deployment isn't suitable. Do you agree with that?

I'm looking for another solution. http://wercker.com/ is one possible solution.

Comment: Someone please answer this question! I was thinking the same but im a noob in terms of deployment

Comment: You can use https://envoyer.io/ (Also build by Taylor Otwell) to deply your site to multiple servers.